# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in asp core and angular7

Tags: javascript, typescript, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

i need to download image from backend Asp Core 2.2 and show it in Angular .

i create a component for show image in angular :

in Html Code :

```
<img [src]="src$ | async" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
```

in Ts File :

```
  @Input() ImagePath: string;
  ImageBlob: any;

  public src$: Observable<SafeUrl>;
  private imageSrc$: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.imageSrc$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    this.src$ = this.imageSrc$.pipe(switchMap(src => this.getImage(this.ImagePath)));
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.imageSrc$.next(this.ImagePath);
  }

  private createImage(blob: Blob) {
    console.log('CREATE_IMAGE');
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }

  private getImage(url: string) {
    console.log('GET_IMAGE');
    return this.downloadService
      .DownloadImage(this.ImagePath)
      .pipe(map((blob: Blob) => this.createImage(blob)));
  }
}
```

and in Service :

```
DownloadImage(ImageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this.httpClient.get(ImageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
 }
```

now when i need to show image it show me this error in console :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44372/Uplaod/NewsPictureFolder/NewsMainPicture/903797628068313.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)

and this is my interceptor :

```
   @Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (req.url.includes('/Upload/')) {
            console.log('upload')
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') })
            return next.handle(req);
        }
        if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            console.log('type')
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') })
        req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
        return next.handle(req);
    }
}
```

i do not know where is the problem ? in Front End or Backend ??

this is Startup in Asp core :

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                  .AllowCredentials()
            .Build());

        });
```

where is the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????

Comment: Try removing `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`

Comment: @JohanP its not work man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 2.2 doesn't allow the combination of `AllowAnyOrigin` and `AllowCredentials`. You need to change `AllowAnyOrigin` to `SetIsOriginAllowed`:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowCredentials()
            );
```

Answer (score 4):

While the other answer is correct, if you however want to define specific allowed origins (and you should), you should remove `.AllowAnyOrigin()` or `SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)` from your CORS statement and it will work with `.AllowCredentials()`.

```
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                  .AllowCredentials()
            .Build());

        });
```

And if you want to allow multiple Origins, you can set an array of origins and use that as the param in `.WithOrigins()`. E.g:

```
private readonly string[] MyAllowedOrigins = new string[] {
    "http://localhost:4200",
    "http://localhost:3000"
};

...
.WithOrigins(MyAllowedOrigins)
...
```

Also, pay attention to the scheme used - check if it's `http` or `https`.

For the sake of completeness, never forget to add e.g. `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");`
where you configure your pipeline, e.g. `.Configure` method in the `Startup` class.

---

All in all - while in some cases allowing any origin could be okay, you usually want and should define the allowed origins specifically.

Regarding `SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)` - this should be an expression to evaluate whether an origin should be allowed, making it return `=> true` always, could be fine under a dev. environment, but shouldn't be used in production as far as I can tell.

You can find a good read on MS Docs. Checkout:

- [Enable Cross-Origin Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [CorsPolicyBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [AllowAnyOrigin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.allowanyorigin?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [WithOrigins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.withorigins?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [SetIsOriginAllowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicybuilder.setisoriginallowed?view=aspnetcore-2.2)