# CORS Issue in .net mvc angular application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, angular, cors

I have an API project in .net with MVC and another project in angular 7. When I try to call a method, the CORS issues occurred. The error message is shown below. Can anyone help to solve the issue? Thanks in Advance

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:55134/UserDetails/GetUserDetails' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have already installed the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` and added

```cs
EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

in the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)

Comment: check this also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015934/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-in-asp-core-and-angular7

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

> Modify the server to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to
>   enable cross-origin requests from anywhere (or specify a domain
>   instead of *).

*Dev-Only:

> Disable Same Origin If this is only for development or learning
>   purposes, the easiest thing to do is to disable the Same Origin Policy
>   in your browser. Be aware that if you do this, you’re opening your
>   browser up to security risks. Follow these instructions: Chrome
>   Firefox This is more of a last resort. Modifying the server to support
>   CORS or running a proxy are the best approaches.*

For More:-
 Refer link:- 
https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

[Deadly CORS when http://localhost is the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin)

https://coderwall.com/p/_ff9dg/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-on-google-chrome-for-javascript-api-calls-and-debugging-purposes

or,
Use chromium:-
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

or,

> Add chrome Extension in chrome:- "Allow CORS:
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Answer (score -1):

There are a few workarounds:

1. Turn of browser security;
2. Use proxy (But these are temprory methods);
3. Set `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":'*'` in both server side and request header in angular.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not a request header and will do nothing.